# How to expire fragment cache when locale changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, internationalization

I'm trying to use fragment cache to cache the footer and navigation bar on a Ruby on Rails Site that uses I18n. The problem is, changing the language then shows you the footer and navigation bar in the wrong language. How do you go about expiring fragment cache when locale changes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than expiring the fragment cache, you should make the locale part of the cache key, i.e. something like

```
cache :locale => I18n.locale, ... do
  ...
end
```

This way different users can see different language versions of the footer/navigation bar but all will see cached versions.

Comment: I knew I'm missing something which is right in front of my eyes and I'm staring at! :) Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Ps if an answer helps you out you should mark the answer as accepted to help people searching for the same thing

Comment: What I've ended up writing is: <% cache "#{I18n.locale}_footer" do %>footer_html_here<% end %>

Answer (score 6):

When caching a fragment in Rails 3, this did the trick for me:

```
- cache([object, locale: I18n.locale]) do
```

Answer (score 1):

I use to have this helper, so I don't need to explicitly pass the locale to each `cache` call:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
module CacheHelper
  # Always using current I18n.locale to cache things.
  def cache(name = {}, options = {}, &block)
    name_with_locale = [name].flatten << I18n.locale.to_s
    super(name_with_locale, options, &block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use cache_with_locale gem.

https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/cache_with_locale