# How to expire conditional GET cache when locale changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, etag

For a JSON API, I am using [`fresh_when`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-fresh_when), like so (simplified):

```
class BalancesController < ApplicationController
  def mine
    fresh_when(current_user.balance)
  end
end
```

This works with ETags (If-None-Match) and updated_at (If-Modified-Since) just fine.

However, I want to invalidate the cache for different languages. Simplified:

```
class BalancesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_locale
  def mine 
    fresh_when(current_user.balance)
  end

  private
  def set_locale
    @locale = locale_from_headers
  end
end
```

`locale_from_headers` is a more complex lib, but for this example it is enough to say that a header `"Accept-Language: nl"` or `"Accept-Language: en"` will result in `@locale` being either `:nl` or `:en`.

I want to use this in the etag and if-modified since. So that the fresh_when does not return a cached response when requesting a different language. Like so:

- `get /balances/mine, {}, { "Accept-Language" => "en" }` #=> response 200 OK
- `get /balances/mine, {}, { "Accept-Language" => "en", "If-None-Match" => previous_response.headers["ETag"] }` #=> response 304 not modified
- `get /balances/mine, {}, { "Accept-Language" => "nl", "If-None-Match" => previous_response.headers["ETag"] }` #=> response 200 OK
- `get /balances/mine, {}, { "Accept-Language" => "nl", "If-None-Match" => previous_response.headers["ETag"] }` #=> response 304 not modified

So, responses are cached and returned as 304 only when the locales match the cached version.

With `cache()` blocks, using fragment caching in Rails, [adding a locale is simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672034/how-to-expire-fragment-cache-when-locale-changes). 
How to achieve the same with the `fresh_when` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. But works only with the etags-method:

```
class BalancesController < ApplicationController
  etag { current_locale }

  def mine 
    fresh_when(etag: current_user.balance)
  end

  private
  def current_locale
    @locale ||= locale_from_headers
  end
end
```

## If-Modified-Since

With the `If-Modified-Since` method, it is not possible to expire the cache. Since Rails does not store any cache when using the `Conditional GET` but only compares passed in timestamps with timestamps on the objects.

Neither of those have the ability to carry more information than "Just a Date". We would need rails to store its caches (like with fragment caching) in order to also store the language it was created for. This method will not allow us to expire a cache based on the language header.

By passing only the `etag` option, the if-modified-since headers are ignored: `fresh_when(etag: current_user.balance)`

## If-None-Match

This represents an entity-tag, and is an identifier for the content being served. Usually this is built using the object-id of the object being returned.

Conditional Get allows extra etag-builders, named `etaggers` [to be defined](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet/ClassMethods.html#method-i-etag).

This can be used to add extra information into the entity-tag.